# R Difference between source and load

Tags: r, load, difference

I dont really understand the differences in the documentaries.
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/load
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/source

When to load a R file or Rdata file? Does it even matter?

Comment: `source()`expects a text file with R code in it that you want to execute. `load()` reads a binary data file that contains R object that were previously created in another R session. So it depends on if you are loading code or objects into your current session.

Comment: text file ? so it loads things like functions while load() loads object into the environment?

Comment: Yes. `source` expects a text file (usually with a .R extension but that's not required). It con contain any command that you would otherwise run in the console. And yes, `load()` loads objects, but those object could be functions or data as well.